# Citing full date in inline citations with biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I'm using biblatex-chicago to format my bibliography, and my professor wants us to cite his lectures with the exact day there were recorded, like this:

```
Last, First. 2020. 8. 5. ``Course Name: Course Description.'' University of State, City.
```

The inline citations are supposed to look like:

```
"...quote quote quote" (Last 2020.8.5).
```

How would I go about formatting this in my .bib file? How would I ensure it shows up like this in my paper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be *extremely* painful to modify `biblatex-chicago` to produce output not in line with CMS requirements. The style does a *lot* of work to be able to meet CMS requirements and uses some very complex code to get everything right.

In general I recommend not trying to modify heavily customised styles such as `biblatex-chicago`, `biblatex-apa`, ... beyond the interfaces they offer.

Here is an *ad-hoc* solution that worked OK in my tests. To avoid messing up things we don't want to mess up, I added a new entry option `fulldate` that you need to explicitly set if you want the full date in citations and the bibliography.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\newtoggle{cbxcms@fulldate}

\makeatletter
\DefineBibliographyExtras{american}{%
  \protected\def\mkdaterangecompextra{%
    \iftoggle{cbxcms@fulldate}
      {\def\bibdatesep{.}%
       \mkdaterangeymdextra}
      {\cms@mkyearrangeextra[]{long}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{date}{% Adding the test solved some issues in 0.9 with
  \iftoggle{cms@switchdates}%
  {\ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{origyear}\AND\iffieldundef{origmonth}%
    \AND\iffieldundef{origday}\AND\iffieldundef{origseason}}%
    {}%
    {\printorigdate}}%
  {\ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{year}\AND\iffieldundef{month}%
    \AND\iffieldundef{day}\AND\iffieldundef{season}}% Punctuation in some
    {}%  entry types (Misc).  The whole \printdate thing may need further work.
    {\iftoggle{cbxcms@fulldate}
       {}
       {\printdate}}}}
\makeatother

\DeclareEntryOption[boolean]{fulldate}[true]{\settoggle{cbxcms@fulldate}{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@performance{elk,
  author      = {Anne Elk},
  title       = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  date        = {1980-04-05},
  institution = {Univ. of Place},
  location    = {Place},
  options     = {fulldate},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{elk}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Elk 1980.4.5)//Elk, Anne. 1980.4.5. A Theory on Brontosauruses. Univ. of Place, Place.]